google apps scriptでカレンダーの「勤務場所」を設定したい
日によってオフィスか自宅かことなります。
スプレッドシートとcalendarAPIを使ってGASで特定の日付の勤務場所を追加していきたいです。
コードが思いつかず助けていただけませんか？
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app?hl=ja
